# How do browsers resolve conflicting classes?

Tags: html, css, dom

I know it's possible to specify multiple classes on an element in HTML:

```
<div class='one two'>Text</div>
```

It seems like classes are accessible from Javascript as a single string.

What happens when the classes are specified with conflicting properties? For instance

```
div.one {
  background-color: red; 
  color: blue;
}
div.two {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Will the result depend on the order the classes are specified in? For instance could I reasonably expect the div above to appear with blue text and a green background, because the `two` class becomes evaluated second, overwriting the `background-color` property?

Comment: It's more the issue of what results are **supposed** to be produced (wrt standards, etc). Sure I could test it on all 8 browsers I'm trying to support but that info may not even be useful two years from now

Comment: Have a read of: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html#cascade

Comment: @FlyBy - I disagree; have you not seen how quickly people answer stuff here???  ;)

Comment: As far as I know it depends on the order of classes in the written css file. In this case it should be blue text on green background no matter if the divs class is `one two` or `two one`. If you change the css and define the `div.two` earlier to the `div.one` you would get blue text on red background...

Comment: The name "cascading" should provide a strong hint -- the 'last' will take precedence and over-ride properties. Anything the child doesn't specify is left up to the parent, all the way up to the page's own stylesheet and default browser styles.

Comment: @Mob this was not specified explicitly but the question is about how to determine if the CSS evaluates to the exact same precedence/specificity level. However, to be pedantic, the docs on that do at some point reveal the answer

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Read about specificity:

- [Simple explanation](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/)
- [More in depth explanation](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Short answer: if two selectors have the same specificity, the last one to be declared wins.

Answer (score 18):

CSS has a very well defined order of precedence.

In instances like this, where all else is the same and the precedence is equal, the browser should pick the style defined last in the stylesheets.

In the example you've given, this would mean that the `div.two` styles would override `div.one`, where the same property is defined in both.

By the way, this is also the same feature that allows you to do define multiple styles with the same property in the same selector, to support different browser features. For example, some browsers may not support rgba colours, so you can do the following:

```
.myclass {
    background: rgb(200, 54, 54);
    background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5);
}
```

All browsers will pick the last `background` declaration that they support, so browsers which support `rgba` will pick the second one, while browsers that don't, will make do with the first one.

It is also the reason why, when you use vendor prefixed styles, you should also specify the non-prefixed version after the prefixed version(s), so that when that vendor's browser does start supporting the non-prefixed version of the style, you can be sure it'll use it rather than the prefixed version (which may not support all the features of the final version).

Comment: except for the color attribute.

Comment: So the problem with putting vendor-prefixed styles after, is that on a browser which supports both versions, it would use the prefixed one (the less "standard" of the supported versions)? I'm not sure why that would turn out to be a problem per se.

Comment: @Steven Lu - re vendor prefixes: the point is that a prefixed version may not support all features that the final version does, but a later version of the browser may continue to support the prefixed version for backward compatibility. But you want the non-prefixed version to take precedence if possible.

Comment: Thanks for including the tip about using order-of-precedence to provide fallbacks in case of unsupported features.

Answer (score 12):

If the selectors have the [same level of precedence](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) (as they do here), whichever is specified *later* takes precedence. In this case, the background should be green, but the font color blue.

From the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order):

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same
>   weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins.
>   Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any
>   declarations in the style sheet itself.

Answer (score 5):

What you are using to style these are called "cascading style sheets".  The cascading part means that it's like a waterfall and future rules build on (or overwrite) previous ones.  Thus the second rule will overwrite the background-color property but it will still retain the font color.

(be careful with precedence though.  a rule that goes off of an id has higher priority over one that goes off of a class regardless of where they are placed.)

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/2NpXS/

Depends on order of stylesheet. Later style declarations take precedence. You can invert the two css lines to see.

Answer (score 2):

The result depend on the order the classes are specified in.

Here's a good write-up on the order in which CSS rules are executed:
http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html